# WebGL indices array size

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, buffer, webgl, indices

For one of my WebGL projects I need to generate lots of objects with indices.
For examples, cones. When JavaScript generates not so many everything works 
fine, by adding another cones to the scene rendering becomes glitchy.

[image: works fine with small number of cones]

[image: glitchy with lots of them]

I am pretty sure that the problem is in defining index buffer:

```
*var iBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint8Array(glIndices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);*
```

To be more specific with **Unit8Array** or its transition to shader.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Sorry, **Uint8Array** of course.

Comment: How about using `Uint16Array`?!

Answer (score 2):

If you use Uint8 for indices you are limiting yourself to a maximum of 256 unique vertices per drawcall, so if you batch a draw it's likely you are exceeding the max value of a Uint8 and integer truncation likely means you just end up with effectvely random vertex connectivity across models.

Increase to a Uint16 indices will let you have 65536 unique vertices per draw.

Comment: That's what I did firstly, but it seems that with changing Uint8Array to Uint16Array I need to change something else, because in this case script always renders the same mess.

Maybe I need change this line somehow:

gl.drawElements( gl.TRIANGLES, indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0 );

Comment: `gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE` != 16 bits.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I posted gl.drawElements line, but I could find by what it should be replaced. I have tried UNSIGNED_SHORT, but the script stops working and maybe I have to change variable type within shader also.

Comment: According to WebGL reference there is only two options: UNSIGNED_BYTE and UNSIGNED_SHORT (16-bit), so I have tried to implement short, but everything stops working returning

_Offscreen-For-WebGL-0x7f9227023400]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: range out of bounds for buffer_

Comment: I have tried this way:

var buf = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buf);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(glIndices),    gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    

var iBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buf);
var indices = [3, 2, 1]; //or 2, 1, 0
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

however it returns _INVALID_OPERATION: bindBuffer: buffers can not be used with multiple targets_ and _INVALID_OPERATION: bufferData: no buffer_

Comment: Please update your question rather than doing it in the comments - it's almost impossible to read code with no formatting. Also please try to post a complete example - it's very hard to debug from snippets of code without any context. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve